# Show that $ f(t)=t^{\gamma}, \gamma \in (0,1), t \geq 0 $ is Hölder continuous

Tags: inequality

I need to show that $ \left| f(t_{0})-f(t_{1}) \right| \leq C\left| t_{0}-t_{1} \right|^{\alpha} $ for some $ C,\alpha \geq 0 $ for all $ t_{0},t_{1}$ in the domain of $ f$.

Since $ f(t) $ is concave,

$$ \frac{f(t_{0})}{2} + \frac{f(t_{1})}{2} \leq f\left(\frac{t_{0}}{2}+\frac{t_{1}}{2} \right) $$
$$ f(t_{0})+f(t_{1}) \leq 2f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)f(t_{0}+t_{1}) $$
$$ \left| f(t_{0})-f(t_{1}) \right| \leq C(t_{0}+t_{1})^{\gamma} $$

But $ (t_{0}+t_{1})^{\gamma} \geq \left| t_{0}-t_{1} \right|^{\gamma} $ which doesn't help. Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Hi, prove that $0 \leq (t_1 + t_2)^a-t_1^a\leq t_2^a$ where $a\in (0,1)$

Answer (score 2):

Claim : $0\leq (x+y)^{a}-x^{a}\leq y^{a}$

Assume that $x >y>0$, $x=y$,$x=0$,$y=0$ is trivial.

Note that : 
$$
(x+y)^{a}-x^{a}=y^{a}\left[\left(1+{\frac  xy}\right)^{a}-\left({\frac  xy}\right)^{a}\right]=y^{a}[(1+X)^{a}-X^{a}]
$$

Let $g(X)=(1+X)^{a}-X^{a}$, $a>0$ then $g(X)>0$
and
$$
g'(X)=a(1+X)^{{a-1}}-aX^{{a-1}}.
$$
$a - 1 < 0$ then $g'(X) < 0$

Therefore, g is decreasing and
$$
\forall X, \quad g(X)\leq g(0)=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly the same you did but start from here:

$$\frac{f(t_0)}{2}+\frac{f(t_1-t_0)}{2}.$$